# SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, google-api

estoy tendiendo el siguiente error en una aplicación aspnetcore 3.1:
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Tengo una aplicación de razor pages de aspnetcore 3.1, la cual en servidor local funciona perfectamente, pero cuando la publico en un servidor remoto me da el error mencionado arriba.

En la aplication estoy usando google Api, que creo que alli donde falla la aplicación. Lo que me extraña es que en local funciona y en el servidor  remoto da error. 
este el la llama a google APi:

```
public static async Task<AddressPoints> GetPlaceNameByCoords(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string lat = latitude.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
        string lng = longitude.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
        Uri url = new Uri($"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng={lat},{lng}&key={GoogleKey}");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(true);
        string urlContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        GoogleGeoModel googleGeoModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleGeoModel>(urlContent);
        if (googleGeoModel.status != "OK")
        {
            return null;
        }
```

//more code
}

¿Alguien sabe porqué? Y como puedo solicionar el error?

Gracias!

Comment: Ponga el código

Comment: suena como a que hace falta abrir los puertos para que haya conexión

Answer (score 0):

La duda ha sido resuelta, y aquí comparto la solución.

El problema era el proxy, y tenia que configurar el proxy según el servidor. el siguiente es el código:

```
 var proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy
        {
            Address = new Uri("http://ejemplo.com")
        };
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = proxy
        };

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```